# Как назначить пользователя "сотрудником"?

Tags: python, django

Такая задумка, есть список пользователей, рядом с которыми есть кнопка, при нажатии которой, выбранный пользователем становится сотрудником (staff). Я понимаю, что это можно реализовать такой функцией

```
  def appoint_as_administrator(request, user_id):
        user = User.objects.filter(id=user_id)
        user.is_staff = True
        user.save()
        return ...
```

Но как сделать это, используя классы?

Comment: Вам нужно подробней объяснить суть проблемы, в особенности требование про классы. Создать класс и поместить туда метод с кодом из вопроса дело нехитрое, но это же, наверно, не то, что вам нужно?

Comment: ну то есть может быть это можно сделать с помощью классов представления?

Comment: Использовать DetailView, FormView из django.views.generic. Смотря, что вам надо. Потому что я не понял с использованием формы или без? Можете использовать метод get_context_data.